# (Beginner) query MongoDB on DBeaver

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Beginner question as I've barely started using DBeaver on querying a MongoDB.

I'd like to run a simple command like:

> db.customer.find( {name: "John"} )

However, I'm getting

```
Command failed with error 10107 (NotMaster): 'not master' on server live-mongodb5.aws.cisha.de:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "not master", "code": 10107, "codeName": "NotMaster"}
```

I tried just `db`, same error. I'm unable to work out what to do next. I tried to follow https://towardsdatascience.com/8-examples-to-query-a-nosql-database-fc3dd1c9a8c to do some queries.

Comment: It seems that you are connected to a secondary node in your replica set, and read operations like `find` are not available by default in secondary nodes. You have to connect to your primary node in order to do write and read operations or make read operations available in your secondary nodes with `rs.secondaryOk()` through mongo shell.

Comment: @biorubenfs Where would I find such information to do it?

Comment: I've never used dbeaver. I need more info. Are you using atlas, local replica set, ...?